# WSDL service reference giving error

Tags: wsdl, asp.net-mvc-5, payment-gateway

I am using a doc data payments gateway service and when I try to give it a request to create an order it throws the following exception:

> XmlSerializer attribute
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute is not valid in
>   version. Only XmlElement, XmlArray, XmlArrayItem, XmlAnyAttribute and
>   XmlAnyElement attributes are supported when IsWrapped is true.

I don't think it is an exception that has anything to do with the service. What am I doing wrong on my side of implementation. Can anyone help me with that?

**EDIT**

I have used DocDataPayments gateway and used the wsdl refrence they give to make the call.

The create call I am making is as follows:-

```
PaymentServiceSOAPClient client = new PaymentServiceSOAPClient();
createSuccess success = new createSuccess();
client.create(merchant, strMTID, paymentPreferences, menuPreferences, shopper, totalGrossAmount, billTo, "description", "Thanks for your purchase", true, new paymentRequest(), new invoice(), new technicalIntegrationInfo(), Convert.ToDecimal(0.9), out success);
```

Comment: How did you create the request?

Comment: @JohnSaunders


`PaymentServiceSOAPClient client = new PaymentServiceSOAPClient();

createSuccess success = new createSuccess();

client.create(merchant, strMTID, paymentPreferences, menuPreferences, shopper, totalGrossAmount, billTo, "description", "Thanks for your purchase", true, new paymentRequest(), new invoice(), new technicalIntegrationInfo(), Convert.ToDecimal(0.9), out success);`

using the above code.

Comment: You should add that information to your question. Did you use "Add Service Reference" to create the `PaymentServiceSOAPClient`, or "Add Web Reference"?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Edited the question. Please check and let me know your response on that.

Comment: Minor note: you don't need to do `= new createSuccess()`, since the call overwrites it.

Answer (score -1):

I think, you are using wcf default serializer to make proxy classes.you can try with DataContract serializer instead default serializer.

Comment: The Data Contract serializer _is_ the default serializer for WCF.